# how to get results outsite of iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i have a IFRAME which will load my login page like :

```
  <iframe src="loginForm.html"></iframe>
```

after submiting this form how to get  results on parent Html page containing IFRAME

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do and what, if anything,is not working.

Comment: i have created a html page. then i have also created three buttons on html page login,register,close when use click on login a popup comes up and shows iframe.  iframe's src is login.html with code i have writen above so i want to get results like login sucess or login fail on main page not under iframe so please help me

Comment: None of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[javascript]access%20iframe%20content) answered your question?

Comment: please help me how to access

Comment: @VikasKandari You do it like in my answer

Comment: now i have edited the question please check and give a suitable answer

Comment: There are 977 answers already, and one more below ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy.
When the verification is over You have to put the result in the var, for example:

```
var verificated = true;
// after verification set it to true or false in iframe
```

Then You have to get this varable out of iframe. You do it like this:

```
var logged = document.getElementById("iFrameID").contentWindow.verificated
```

You can then put it on screen when you are logged in.

```
alert(logged) // Will alert true if logged, or false if not
```

I would also use AJAX to log in

**EDIT**

What you asked in comment:

You can get to your p element just like that:

```
document.getElementById("iFrameID").contentWindow.getElementById("pElementId").innerText;
```

You can then alert it or write it somewhere ont he page

**EDIT 2**

textContent is a W3C standart, but it doesn't work on IE<9

Unlikely to innerText, it displays text from `<Style>` tags and similar

Comment: can i access innerHtmls of iframe supose i have a <p> element to display the massage under iframe n i want to access innertext of p element in to main_page

Comment: @VikasKandari Yes, I edited my post

Comment: What is `innerTEXT`?

Comment: @Teemu It gets all the text from the div or other element... Didn't You know that?

Comment: sorry its innerHtml  how to get its text like "unable to login check password or username"

Comment: No, that property is `textContent` by standard, `innerText` is implemented in Chrome and IE only.

Comment: @VikasKandari What? What are you asking? Your english is not very good

Comment: @Teemu well yes, I edited my post.

Comment: @VikasKandari try `document.getElementById("iFrameID").contentWindow.getElementById("pElementId").textContent`

Comment: @VikasKandari Did it work? It has to work. You just get to a p's text: `getElementById("pElementId").‌​textContent` like You normally do, but firstly You have to access the iframe, so the code is: `document.getElementById("iFrameID").contentWindow.getElementById("pElementId").‌​textContent`

Comment: @VikasKandari DID IT WORK?

Comment: now i have edited the question please check and give a suitable answer